# C# page keeps sending old data

Tags: c#

So I hava a page where the user gives data for the app to send it to a database.
When the user clicks on next the app navigates to the next page. But when the user goes back and edits the data the app still saves the old data from the first input to the database.

For example:

Name : Jon Do

The user made a mistake and goes to the previous pageL

Name : John Doe

The user clicks next and the data gets saved to the database. But except of saving the new data "John Doe" it sends the old data, "Jon Do". This, ofcourse, should not happen. I have no clue why this happens.

Here is my C# code of the page where the user should give his/her data

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ckbGegevens.IsChecked == false)
        {
            try
            { 
                dt.saveData = true;
                dt.bedrijfsNaam = txxBvName.Text;
                dt.contactPersoon = txxContPersn.Text;
                dt.telNummer = Convert.ToInt32(txxTelNr.Text);
                dt.eMail = txxEMail.Text;
                dt.land = txxLand.Text;
                dt.plaats = txxPlaats.Text;
                dt.postcode = txxPostCode.Text;

                postToJson.post("bvg");
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Doelen());
            }
            catch (Exception) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Er ontbreken gegevens!\nOf u heeft ongeldige gegevens ingevuld!");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            try {
                dt.bedrijfsNaam = txxBvName.Text;
                dt.contactPersoon = txxContPersn.Text;
                dt.telNummer = Convert.ToInt32(txxTelNr.Text);
                dt.eMail = txxEMail.Text;
                dt.land = txxLand.Text;
                dt.plaats = txxPlaats.Text;
                dt.postcode = txxPostCode.Text;
                dt.saveData = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Uw gegevens worden niet opgeslagen.\nVink voor optimaal gebruik deze functie aan.");
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Doelen());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I save it to the database:

```
 static string bedrijfsNaam = dt.bedrijfsNaam;
    static string ContPers = dt.contactPersoon;
    static int TelNum = dt.telNummer;
    static string email = dt.eMail;
    static string Land = dt.land;
    static string Plaats = dt.plaats;
    static string PostCode = dt.postcode;
    static string json;
    static string b64encode;

    public postToJson(string reqCat)
    {

    }

    public static void post(string reqCat)
    {
        if (reqCat == "bvg")
        {
            json = "{\"bedrijfsNaam\":\"" + bedrijfsNaam + "\"," +
                "\"ContPers\":\"" + ContPers + "\"," +
                "\"TelNum\":\"" + TelNum + "\"," +
                "\"email\":\"" + email + "\"," +
                "\"Land\":\"" + Land + "\"," +
                "\"Plaats\":\"" + Plaats + "\"," +
                "\"PostCode\":\"" + PostCode + "\"}";

            var b64bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            b64encode = System.Convert.ToBase64String(b64bytes);
            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["b64string"] = b64encode;
            data["filename"] = dt.bedrijfsNaam;

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var sendB64 = client.UploadValues("http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scripturi"].ToString() + "SalesKicker.php", "POST", data);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem isn't in the PHP script so I don't have to post that script. I know this because I printed out the result of the JSON. Which always has the data from the first input.
Can someone please tell  me what is going on here?

Comment: log out and log back in and then see if it worked

Comment: What is `dt`? And where's the code that performs the actual save operation? And is information actually updated even when `ckbGegevens.IsChecked == false`? There too little information to answer this question.

Comment: yes but then it doesn't save it to the database. dt is a class with some datatypes.

Comment: @B.Hulshof We can't see the rest of your code, you need to be saving it to the database. Are you doing this?

Comment: if your are modifying the same record then there must be update operation right?

Comment: It's not the query, it's my C# script

Comment: I'm assuming from your comments that you've put a breakpoint in the btnNext_click method, and that, for example, txxBvName.Text does not have the value you expect in this scenario.  If so, then you probably haven't posted the correct code to highlight your problem.  You should delete all the example code above dealing with the SQL, and instead post the code that builds the controls for the page.  As a debugging tip, put a breakpoint in Page_Init and example the Request.Form collection.  This shows all values from the client.

Comment: @BertCushman this doesn't even make sense to me. And my C# doesn't deal with SQL at all, because that is very unsafe and not secure at all. I'm dealing with a REST api. This code I posted is very relevant.

Comment: But if the value of the control is wrong when you first get into the method, then what you do in the method is unimportant.

Comment: The value is whatever the user puts in, and there are checks for when the input is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The assignments seem to be done in the declaration of the static class, thereby they will only happen once and you don't know when. Therefore you should put these in a separate method:

```
static string bedrijfsNaam = dt.bedrijfsNaam;
static string ContPers = dt.contactPersoon;
static int TelNum = dt.telNummer;
static string email = dt.eMail;
static string Land = dt.land;
static string Plaats = dt.plaats;
static string PostCode = dt.postcode;
```

And then call that method in the post method.

E.g.

```
private static void updateData() {
    bedrijfsNaam = dt.bedrijfsNaam;
    ContPers = dt.contactPersoon;
    TelNum = dt.telNummer;
    email = dt.eMail;
    Land = dt.land;
    Plaats = dt.plaats;
    PostCode = dt.postcode;
}
```

Comment: Why would I have to put this in another method?

Comment: Because then you can update the data whenever it is required. At this moment you are not updating the data. That the data is set in those variables as now only done on creation of the static class, i.e. only once.

Comment: To clarify: you are for example setting dt.contactPersoon and then using ContPers which is not the same variable.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to me. The data gets set whenever the user clicks on the button. So this method wouldn't really do much, would it?

Comment: Yes the data gets set when the user clicks a button, but you do not use *that* data to generate your JSON message.